# Erro ao ligar 2 base de dados postgres com FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, import

Estou a tentar fazer a ligação entre 2 bases de dados postgres e estou a receber erro ao importar as tabelas:

```
CREATE EXTENSION postgres_fdw;
CREATE SERVER gestware_server
  FOREIGN DATA WRAPPER postgres_fdw
  OPTIONS (host 'localhost', dbname 'gwrcsgf1');

CREATE USER MAPPING FOR CURRENT_USER
  SERVER gestware_server
  OPTIONS (user 'postgres', password 'senha');

CREATE SCHEMA app;

IMPORT FOREIGN SCHEMA public
  FROM SERVER gestware_server
  INTO app'
```

Recebo a mensagem:

> 'ERROR:  syntax error at or near "IMPORT" LINE 1: IMPORT FOREIGN
>   SCHEMA public'

Comment: Seu comando IMPORT me parece incompleto. Verifique sua postagem.

Comment: Verifique também a versão do postgres. Esse comando só está disponível a partir da 9.5

Comment: Foi isso que aconteceu. A minha versão é a 12.1 mas a base de dados remota está na 9.3. Utilizei para este caso o 'CREATE FOREIGN TABLE'